# Non homogenous Poisson process with simple rates

Tags: r, simulation, poisson-process

I am trying to stimulate number of claims in the next 12 months using a non-homogeneous poisson process. The rates are:

```
11.02 per day, during March, April and May
11.68 per day, during June, July and August
26.41 per day, during September, October, November
20.83 per day, during December, Jan and Feb
```

I came across the inversion method, which seems the simplest for simple rates like in my case (compared to the thinning method).

I tried to follow the algorithm:

```
s=0; v=seq(0,Tmax,length=1000)
   X=numeric(0)
   while(X[length(X)]<=Tmax){
     u=runif(1)
     s=s-log(u)
     t=min(v[which(Vectorize(Lambda)(v)>=s)])
     X=c(X,t)
   }
```

but how do I set my lambda to change depending on the month??

Comment: Hope to come back to this one for a full-length answer (w/ code) but until then there are some resources [here](http://radhakrishna.typepad.com/simulating-nonhomogeneous-poisson-process.pdf), [here](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~pasupath/PAPERS/2011pasB.pdf), and [this one is nice](https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/724).

Comment: thank you for the resources! I would love your full length answer with code since I’ve been googling for days with no luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Your rate function,$\,\lambda(t)$, will look something like the image below if I understand what you're asking. To do the procedure I think you're referencing, you need the rate function $\lambda(t)$ and the cumulative rate function, $\Lambda(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(s)ds$.
[image: RateFunction]

**Generate a Homogeneous Poisson Process (NHPP) via Nonlinear Time Transformation**
Task:  generate $\{N(t),t\ge 0\}$ which is an NHPP with rate $\lambda(t)$
Given: target rate function $\lambda(t)$.

Let $N_0(t)$ be a rate-1 Poisson process (i.e. $\lambda = 1$). Let $\text{E}[N(t)] = m(t)$.  Then $m(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(s)ds$.

Let $N(t) = N_0(m(t))$. Then the counting process $\{N(t),t\ge 0\}$ is a NHPP with rate $\lambda(t)$.

**Procedure**
1. Generate arrival times $S_1^{(0)},S_2^{(0)},S_3^{(0)},\ldots$ for a rate-1 Poisson Process with interarrival times $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots \sim \text{Exponential}(1)$.
2. Use the nonlinear time transformation to obtain event times: $0\le \tilde S_1 \le \tilde S_2 \le \tilde S_3 \le \cdots$ where $\tilde S_n = m^{-1}\left(S_n^{(0)}\right)$.
3. Construct the counting process $N(t) \equiv \text{max}\{n\ge 0:\tilde S_n \le t\}$.

If I can find time, I'll post some working code.  Hope this helps.

---

I bootlegged the rate function like so (as an example only, the total number of days is off). All my implementations of this have been in MATLAB.

```
Rate = [0;ones(90,1)*11.02;
        ones(90,1)*11.68;
        ones(90,1)*26.41;
        ones(90,1)*20.83];
```

---

Update:  Added Thinning Method w/ short comparison [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/369294).

Comment: This method is sort of similar to the link you provided (the nice one) right? I tried (really did) to follow that, but i got stuck in setting up a function for my lambda because the rates are fixed

Comment: Yes, that's right. Same idea.  Have you tried the thinning approach?  I find it is more intuitive and easier to code.

Comment: I found it difficult to use thinning :( i saw ur codes whats the equivalent for ones() in R?

Comment: If i was going to use the thinning approach, am i correct ib saying that i need a lambda star that is bigger than all lambda(t), so i can use 27 in my case?

Comment: You can use 26.41 as the majorizing rate if you want.

Comment: See code [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/369294).